# Facebook Like button_count not working unless logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have added the Facebook button "LIKE" code below:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
                        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mypageinfacebook?sk=myappId" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="21" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

But the like count is not seen on my site, it could be seen only after login in to Facebook account.

How to fix it?

Comment: Having the same issues here.. Did you ever find a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

your code wise no wrong..,

Check your data-href  link has valid one,

```
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mypageinfacebook?sk=myappId"
```

i tried this code with my fans page url its shown the like counts perfectly..

otherwise, 
the page which users wants to like might having `'0'` likes.

if that case means count wont show.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better to use this one this reference is working..

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Answer (score 0):

Posting this response for other users that come across this post.

"It seems you are using restriction on "minimum age" or "country" on your page.

That mean facebook can't display a like box, without knowing who is connected, because he can't know the age or the country of the current user."

All credit to AHWEBDEV

[Link](https://github.com/AHWEBDEV/Facebook-AWD/issues/89)